# Rails form fields empty after submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This is my form:

```
<%= form_tag("/adverts", :method => "get") do %>
Order by: 
<%= select_tag :order_by, options_for_select([['Ascending', 'ASC'], ['Descending', 'DESC']])%>

<%= text_field_tag :text%>

<%= submit_tag 'Change' %>
<% end %>
```

In my Adverts controller, index method, for now I am not doing anything and I can see that it is getting correct values from form,

=>but when page reloads after submission, fields values are empty but I want them to retain values.

So if I enter some text in text field, that text will still be there after submitting form .

Comment: Did you look at the API for [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)? That's where you can find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<%= select_tag :order_by, options_for_select([['Ascending', 'ASC'], ['Descending', 'DESC']], params[:order_by]) %>
```

and:

```
<%= text_field_tag :text, params[:text] %>
```

See the API for [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

Comment: A more appropriate answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the form for an object if you want it to automatically get the objects values on reload.

```
<%= form_for @object do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %> <!-- automatically gets re-populated with the value of @object on postback -->
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If you really want to use form tags instead of a builder then you need to set the values manually after postback

```
<%= text_field_tag :text, some_string_value %>
```

Comment: @Mischa I only said it needs an object if OP wants it to re-populate automatically, which is true. Using form tags requires manually re-populating the values, as I also explain in the answer. Your answer is more direct so I'll upvote that one, but leave my answer for additional context.